# Tree Problems - Understanding when to implement iterative solution v.s. when to implement recursive solution

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, iteration, time-complexity

I've been working on algorithm problems in my free time as a way to prep for interviews for summer internships next summer. I'm currently working on tree problems, and I've found that the actual coding is pretty trivial for most problems, but I have a hard time understanding the complexity of these problems. A problem I was working on is Binary tree Preorder Traversal, and I implemented it both recursively and iteratively. However, the iterative solution was much slower, and I don't understand why? here are my two solutions:

**Iterative:**

```
public List<Integer> preorder(TreeNode root) {
    List<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();

    if (root == null) return ans;

    stack.push(root);

    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode node = stack.pop();
        ans.add(node.val);

        if (node.right != null) stack.push(node.right);
        if (node.left != null) stack.push(node.left);
    {

    return ans;
}
```

**Recursive:**

```
public list<Integer> preorder(TreeNode root) {
    List<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    dfs(root, ans);
    return ans;
}

public void dfs (TreeNode root, List<Integer> ans) {
    if (root == null) return;
    ans.add(root.val);
    dfs(root.left);
    dfs(node.right)
}
```

As far as I can see, the recursive solution has two branches per call, and the depth of the tree if balanced is O(log n), however worst case is O(n), so the complexity would be O(2^n). I could be completely off and probably am. The iterative solution has constant push and pop time, so my initial intuition was that it would be O(n) time. If these were the circumstances, I can't see how the exponential solution would run faster. If somebody could help me understand the complexities of such problems that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many billion billion billion nodes did you test on? O() relates to the asymptotic behavior of an algorithm and unless you are close to that behavior your algorithm runtime has little to do with O() performance. In your case you have a managed stack object or a CPU stack and, guess what ... the CPU stack is faster than yours because it does no heap allocations.

Comment: If you want to understand how many operations your code does, add a counter. It will be the same in each case because you visit each node once.

Answer (score 4):

Time complexity is O(n) in both cases: you visit each node once and do constant amount of work per node (adding value to `ArrayList` or `Stack` is amortized O(1)).

One of the reasons why your iterative solution is slower might be usage of `Stack`. This class is synchronized (it extends `Vector`). You don't need thread-safety in this case, so consider replacing it with `ArrayDeque`:

```
Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
```

Space complexity is also O(n) in both cases: explicit stack in the iterative solution and implicit call stack in the recursive solution can grow to `n` (unbalanced case).

Answer (score 1):

Something having constant complexity vs exponential does not mean it's faster. It just says something about the rate it will get slower as your input grows. I'd say that this is a pretty valuable lesson in itself for interviews and the real world, as the solution with the lowest O-time often isn't the 'best' or more practical.

Aside from the complexity though, I can see that the stack-based approach could just be slower just because it needs to pop and push items on the `stack`, whereas the recursive solution only needs to call a function. I can't say this with certainty without doing a benchmark.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. O-time really just measures how well your algorithm will scale as your inout gets larger, no? In this situation, is it fair to say that the complexities are relatively similar as DFS is O(V + E)? I just get confused as to when it makes more sense to implement an algorithm iteratively vs recursively.

Comment: @bh13 my intuition is that they have the same complexity, but to be 100% honest I can't say that with 100% certainty. I've never been great at these.

Comment: Back to the practical side, with a large enough input, the recursive function might simply fail, due to a stack overflow error. If I encountered this in the real world I would likely go with the simple recursive function, except for very large inputs =)